# What is the difference between a XmlCofigurator and a DomCofigurator in log4net dll?

Tags: log4net

I used both of them it is working fine. but i just want to know the difference for learning purpose?

Answer (score 1):

DomConfigurator is obsolete and replaced by XmlConfigurator:

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.DOMConfigurator.html